# How to upload base64encoded image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a base64 encoded image string `$imgcode` which is a base64 encoded image, and I want to upload it using codeigniter.

Here is what i am doing -

```
$this->Photo_model->uploadPhoto($userdir,base64_decode($imgCode)
```

The uploadPhoto function is this:

```
public function uploadPhoto($path,$img){

    //echo $img;
    //echo $path;

    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload($img)){
        return FALSE;  
    }
    else{ 
        $fInfo = $this->upload->data();
        $this->createThumbnail($fInfo['file_name'],$fInfo['file_path']);  

        $this->load->model('Photo_model');
        if($this->Photo_model->savePhotoInfo($fInfo['file_name'],$path)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The image is not getting uploaded. Is this the correct way?

Comment: I removed the actual string, which almost crashed my browser when I tried to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

There have been reports of various kinds of failures when base64_decode is used to decode large files. You can see more about the problems here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php#105512

I recommend splitting the string like this
`$decodedstring=base64_decode(chunk_split($encodedstring));`