# Unable to upload a base64 encoded image using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to upload a base64 encoded image that i am receiving from android application. I am using php codeigniter framework. 
While searching through the forum, the question at this link [How to upload base64encoded image in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976806/how-to-upload-base64encoded-image-in-codeigniter) is same as mine, but the solution there is not working for me.

Here is the code that i have written:

```
private function _save_image() {
    $image = base64_decode($_POST['imageString']);
    #setting the configuration values for saving the image
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'path_to_image_folder';
    $config['file_name'] = 'my_image'.$_POST['imageType'];
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload($image)) {
        $arr_image_info = $this->upload->data();
        return ($arr_image_info['full_path']);
    }
    else {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        die();
    }
}
```

I am getting "you did not select a file to upload"

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is occurring because codeigniter's upload library will look into the `$_FILES` superglobal to and search for a index you give it at the `do_upload()` call.

Furthermore (at least in version 2.1.2) even if you would set up the $_FILES superglobal to mimic the behaviour of a file upload it wouldn't pass because the upload library uses [is_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to detect exacly that kind of tampering with superglobals. You can trace the code in system/libraries/Upload.php:134

I'm afraid that you will have to re-implement size checking and file renaming and moving (I would do this) or you can modify codeigniter to omit that check, but it could make upgrading the framework later difficult.

1. Save the $image variable's content to a temporary file, and set up the `$_FILES` to look like this:

   ```
    $temp_file_path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'androidtempimage'); // might not work on some systems, specify your temp path if system temp dir is not writeable
    file_put_contents($temp_file_path, base64_decode($_POST['imageString']));
    $image_info = getimagesize($temp_file_path); 
    $_FILES['userfile'] = array(
        'name' => uniqid().'.'.preg_replace('!\w+/!', '', $image_info['mime']),
        'tmp_name' => $temp_file_path,
        'size'  => filesize($temp_file_path),
        'error' => UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
        'type'  => $image_info['mime'],
    );
   ```
2. Modify the upload library. You can use codeigniter's built in [way of Extending Native Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html), and define a My_Upload (or your prefix) class, copy-paste the do_upload function and change the following lines:

   ```
   public function do_upload($field = 'userfile')
   ```

   to:

   ```
   public function do_upload($field = 'userfile', $fake_upload = false)
   ```

   and the:

   ```
   if ( ! is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name']) )
   ```

   to:

   ```
   if ( ! is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name']) && !$fake_upload )
   ```

   and in your controller, call do_upload() with the flowing parameters:

   ```
   $this->upload->do_upload('userfile', true);
   ```

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply. I made the changes as per your guidelines but i am getting the following errors:
1. Undefined index at line number 86 which is ` $this->file_name = $this->_prep_filename($_FILES[$field]['name']); ` in the do_upload function i copied in the MY_Upload class.
2. The file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed. This the output of the print_r ` Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\and15BC.tmp [size] => 354129 [error] => 0 [type] => image/png ) )`

Comment: I've forgotten about the 'name' key in the `$_FILES`, updated the example to, that should fix both errors.

Comment: Hi complex857,
The image upload function is working fine on my system, which is windows 7, wamp. But today i uploaded it to the server, and the code is not working there. I am getting 'You did not select a file to upload' this message. I echoed the output of file_put_contents() function and as per documentation i am getting the number of bytes count. Please help me. If it is of any use, the server on which i have to run this is an amazon ec2 linux server.

Comment: Sounds like CI didn't find your MY_Upload class. Check the uppercase/lowercase chars in the filenames, windows doesn't case sensitive while unix systems are. You can check if its working by printing the classname of the `$this->upload` instance in your controllers. `print get_class($this->upload);` should show `MY_upload`.

Comment: Thanks again !  i had saved the file as My_upload instead of MY_Upload. Its working correctly now at both the places. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are aware, that if you are receiving an Base64 encoded image, as a string, then you do not need to use the Upload class.

Instead, you just need to decode it using base64_decode and then use fwrite/file_put_contents to save the decoded data...

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($string)); 
if($img != false) 
{ 
   imagejpeg($img, '/path/to/new/image.jpg'); 
}
```

Credit: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10359450-RESOLVED-Saving-Base64-image.