# In windows temp file with 0 KB created using base 64 decoded data using file_put_contents

Tags: php, base64

- **Basic purpose**: To upload a croped file.

  - **Language**: PHP
  - **Framework**: Codeigniter
  - **Crop Library**: cropperjs
  - **OS**: Windows 10

I want to create a temp file with base64 data, somehow it is getting created as 0 KB, that is no data in it.
I am referring the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579060

By Code is as below:

```
$temp_file_path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'user_photo'); // might not work on some systems, specify your temp path if system temp dir is not writeable
$can_crop = true;
$base_64_image = explode( ',', $_POST['image-thumb']);
if(sizeof($base_64_image) > 1) {
    if (file_put_contents($temp_file_path, base64_decode($base_64_image[1]) == false)) {
        $can_crop = false;
    }
} else {
    $can_crop = false;
}
```

Here, the file_put_contents is returning the actual size of the data which means the contents are copied to the file, but when I see my temp file, it is of 0KB, I saw if there is any content or not by editing, but it was blank.

Note: previously it was working if I was not exploding the image data, i.e.

```
data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4'
```

But as I am exploding the actual content and decoding the base_64 data i.e.
`AAAFBfj42Pj4` it is creating files in 0 KB.

I searched couple of questions but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brace is put in wrong place in your condition. It should be:

```
if (file_put_contents($temp_file_path, base64_decode($base_64_image[1])) === false) {
```